# how to make two queries atomic in parse.com in beforeSave and afterSave triggers

Tags: parse-platform, triggers, atomic

I made two classes in parse User(by default) and UserData. 
BeforeSave Trigger as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
var userDataObject = new Parse.Object("UserData");
var fromUserPointer = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":request.object.id}; 

return userDataObject.save({score: 0, ideasCount: 0, followersCount:0, return:0}).then(function (userData) {
    var userDataPointer = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"UserData","objectId":userData.id};
    request.object.set("userData", userDataPointer);
    response.success();
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error.message);
});
```

});

It saves user's UserData and takes its UserData pointer field and saves in UserData class.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {   
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var userPointer = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":request.object.id};
var userData = request.object.get("userData");
if (userData) {
    var userDataPointer = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"UserData","objectId":userData.id};
    var userDataQuery = new Parse.Query("UserData");
    userData.set("user", userPointer);
    return userData.save().then (function (userData) {
        var activityObject = new Parse.Object("Activity");
        return activityObject.save({fromUserData: userDataPointer, from:userPointer, 
            toUserData:userDataPointer, to:userPointer, type:"follow"});
    }).then (function (success) {

    }, function (error) {
        console.error("Error in afterSave(user) : " + request.object.id + ":" + error.message);
    });     
}
```

});

The problem is that, before saving in the User class, it sometimes does not create UserData, which it should create. Hence these two triggers must run atomically, which they do not.

Comment: FYI: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: still I need the solution for this .

Comment: you can't make it atomic, it's a set of async requests.

Comment: thanks for suggestion